# How to request confirmation on program exit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, signals, sigint

**I want to request a plaintext password when the user tries to close the script.**

This is my code so far, the unrelated parts are hidden.

```
import signal
from time import sleep

_password = "iAmAdmin"


def _close(args):
    """Close the application."""
    if input("Preparing to close application.\n"
             "Please provide authentication password: ") == _password:
        print("Password correct. Application closing.")
        exit()
    else:
        print("Invalid password. Program will continue in 5 seconds.")
        sleep(5)


# Signal handler.
def sighandler(sig, frame):
    _close(None)


# Initiate the interface.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sighandler)
    clear()  # Function to clear the terminal.
    start()  # Display beginning help message.
    loop()  # An infinite loop requesting input and running functions.
```

When this script is run, and `CTRL+C` is pressed, this is the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "interface.py", line 96, in <module>
Preparing to close application.
Please provide authentication password:
```

And if `SIGINT` is sent again during this it closes silently. It should be ignored until the user inputs the correct password.

If the user does type the correct password, the application crashes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "interface.py", line 96, in <module>
Preparing to close application.
Please provide authentication password: password
Invalid password. Program will continue in 5 seconds.
    loop()
  File "interface.py", line 67, in loop
    cmd = input(_prompt)
EOFError
```

Clearly there's something I'm missing. What is it?

**Edit:** By request, here is the code in the `loop()` function (contains line 67).

```
# All interface functionality below.
def loop():
    """Infinite loop that handles all interface commands."""
    while True:
        cmd = input(_prompt)  # Line 67.
        cmd, args = cmd.lower().split(" ", 1) if " " in cmd else (cmd, None)

        if cmd == "help":
            _help(cmds, args)
        elif cmd in cmds:
            cmds[cmd](args)
        else:
            print("Unrecognized command:", cmd, "\nType \"help\" for a list of commands.")

            suggestions = _suggest(cmds, cmd)

            if suggestions:
                print("\nDid you mean \"" + suggestions[0] + "\"?")

                if len(suggestions) > 1:
                    print("Similar commands:", ", ".join(suggestions[-1:]))
```

Comment: What does the file interface.py in line 67 contain? There's nothing wrong with the code you have shared. You may need to recheck the rest of the code

Comment: Rather than using a signal handler, I would try `try ... except KeyboardInterrupt:`.

Comment: @xaav Where would you put that? It could go anywhere. It also wouldn't solve the problem of the user pressing the buttons twice.

Comment: Let me type an answer at the risk of downvoting.

Comment: @zeeks I have added the code to the question. See the edit I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from getpass import getpass
from time import sleep
from os import system, name as os_name


def clear():
    system("cls") if os_name == "nt" else system("clear")


def close():
    try:
        clear()
        password = getpass("Please provide authentication password to close the application.")
        if password == "admin":
            print("Password correct. Closing application now.\n")
            exit()
        else:
            print("Password incorrect. Application continues in 5 seconds.")
            sleep(5)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError):
        close()


def loop():
    while True:
        cmd = input("> ")
        if cmd == "close":
            close()
        else:
            print("Hello World!")


def main():
    clear()
    try:
        loop()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError):
        close()
        main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It doesn't. It just exits with a blank traceback.

Comment: I checked it in IPython and it seemed to work as advertised. Note that the `guts` and `verifyPassword` functions actually need to do something for this to work.

Comment: Are you saying that i need to call `guts()` in `_verifyPassword()`?

Comment: If the password is not verified, then yes. Also, you could start `guts` in another thread if you don't want it to stop while the password is being verified.

Comment: Here is my adaptation of the code you gave me. Everything works, except when I press `CTRL+C` when the prompt (`> `) is showing.

https://pastebin.com/shjR3tj9

And here is the traceback https://pastebin.com/rHrcWqjG

Comment: I sent you a link to the traceback, so no.

Comment: I updated the answer after you posted that traceback.

Comment: That should work, should have thought of that. But why does it happen?